# Capture volume up button press?

Tags: javascript, firefox-os

*Can a Firefox OS app detect when the volume up button has been pressed? If so, how?*

(maybe it's just a key event on `document`, haven't tried that yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bug 989198](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=989198) is the bug to expose keydown/keyup events to apps. And this [wiki page](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI/BrowserAPI/KeyboardEvent#Dispatch_KeyboardEvent_across_BrowserElements) describes this new `KeyboardEvent` dispatching mechanism. Currently on FFOS phone **v2.2 and later** version, only `VolumeUp` and `VolumeDown` key events will get dispatched into apps.

**On FFOS 2.2 and later**, any apps could listen to `keydown` or `keyup` event of volume-up and volume-down buttons.
The events dispatched to handlers are regular `KeyboardEvent`s (the same as in desktop browser). When user press volume-down or volume-up, KeyboardEvent with `.key` = `VolumeDown` or `VolumeUp` will get dispatched to focused app. And if you want to prevent system app to process them (i.e. to turn volume down or up), just simply call `event.preventDefault()` in your key event handler.

Here's an example of `keydown` event handling:

```
var keyDownHandler = function(evt) {
  if (evt.key === 'VolumeDown') {
    // process logic of volume-down
  } else if (evt.key === 'VolumeUp') {
    // process logic of volume-up
  }
  evt.preventDefault(); // to stop system app from processing keydown event
};

window.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler);
```

Comment: Confirmed to work with 2.2.0.0-prerelease on my Flame.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore with today's 3.0.0.0-prerelease. Just filed that as bug [1138745](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1138745).

Comment: Does it work when the screen is locked? If not, does it matter if it's a PWA?